# React setState in function or setState in useCallback

Tags: reactjs

This looks simple but I am trying to find the best way of handling the state change, I know `useCallback` needed for large application but created the simple example for better understanding and deep analysis.

So I want to understand which one is better approach with `useCallback` or without `useCallback` for less re-render and create function only once.

In this code we are setting `setState` in `onCheckChange`, without `useCallback`.

```
const App = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)

  // Without UseCallback
  const onCheckChange = () => {
    setChecked(!checked);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="checkbox" onChange={onCheckChange} checked={checked} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this code state will be updated through `useCallback` to avoid re-creation of `onCheckChange`

```
const App = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)

  // Callback to update Sate
  const onCheckChange = useCallback(() => {
    setChecked(checked => !checked);
  }, [setChecked]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="checkbox" onChange={onCheckChange} checked={checked} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could simply write since the identity of the function `setChecked` never changes.

```
const onCheckChange = useCallback(() => {
  setChecked(checked => !checked);
}, []);
```

> **Note**
>
> React guarantees that setChecked function identity is stable and won’t
> change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect
> or useCallback dependency list.

Comment: Yes it's true that `setChecked` re-render the component but the purpose of `useCallback` is to avoid redeclaring the variable (onCheckChange) with a new value on each render.

Comment: @ineffablep In that case, you don't need to put `setChecked` in the dependencies array, since the identity of `setChecked` doesn't change.

Comment: See the answer above. @ineffablep

Comment: Your answer is empty dependency list, doesn't it means to re-crate every render

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: How can we check in chrome tools with memory address to see re-created or not in  3 ways.

Comment: You could check the sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-roman-d3ut6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: NIce @PrateekThapa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238944/discussion-between-ineffable-p-and-prateek-thapa).